# How do I send push notification to all users except the current one?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm creating my first Xamarin app and I have a problem sending push notification to all users but not the current one (via Firebase).

I don't fully understand how it works, I suppose that I have to work with receiver tokens but how can I get them? Because for now I can't even send a notification to a single device.

What I have is an app and a firebase project connected with it, so having server key and sender id list of receivers should be the only thing lacking.

Comment: Yes, you're going to have to collect device tokens for all your users, associated each token to the individual user of that device, then iterate all those tokens and omit the ones for the user who should not receive the notification.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is I can't say if someone has unistalled my app and I have to iterate also inactive devices but if that's the best solution I'll do it like this

Comment: That's the way it works, yes.